# Barba.js (аналог Pjax.js) и работа с ним

Tags: javascript, jquery, pjax

В общем-то, сейчас использую [barba.js](http://barbajs.org/) для перехода по страницам без перезагрузки и создания плавной анимации.

Не поленился соорудить [пример](http://agstudio.pro/project/barba/), чтоб было понятие того, как это дело выглядит и работает.

Вот сокращенный вид кода:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {

    Barba.Pjax.init();
    Barba.Prefetch.init();

    var FadeTransition = Barba.BaseTransition.extend({
        start: function() {
            Promise
                .all([this.newContainerLoading, this.fadeOut()])
                .then(this.fadeIn.bind(this));
        },

        fadeOut: function() {
            return $(this.oldContainer).animate({
                opacity: 0
            }).promise();
        },

        fadeIn: function() {
            var _this = this;
            var $el = $(this.newContainer);

            $(this.oldContainer).hide();

            $el.css({
                visibility: 'visible',
                opacity: 0
            });

            $el.animate({
                opacity: 1
            }, 400, function() {
                _this.done();
            });
        },

        newContainer: function() {
            var $newPageHead = $('<head />').html(
                $.parseHTML(
                    newPageRawHTML.match(/<head[^>]*>([\s\S.]*)<\/head>/i)[0], document, true
                )
            );
        },

        done: function() {
            var headTags = [
                "meta[name='keywords']",
                "meta[name='description']",
                "meta[property^='og']",
                "meta[name^='twitter']",
                "meta[itemprop]",
                "link[itemprop]",
                "link[rel='prev']",
                "link[rel='next']",
                "link[rel='canonical']"
            ].join(',');
            $('head').find(headTags).remove();
            $newPageHead.find(headTags).appendTo('head');
        }
    });

    Barba.Pjax.getTransition = function() {
        return FadeTransition;
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/barba.js/0.0.10/barba.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="uMenuRoot">
  <li><a href="/"><span>Home</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="/about.html"><span>About us</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="/contacts.html"><span>Contacts</span></a></li>
</ul>

<main id="barba-wrapper">
  <section class="barba-container middle">
    Page content   
  </section>
</main>
```

Перелопатил все что можно в поисках наличия решения. **Итак вопрос!** Можно ли заставить перезагружать содержимое `<head>`? То есть, извлечь содержимое данного тега и заменить уже загруженное.

Немного дополним вопрос, изменив задачу. Было бы неплохо подменять не все стили и скрипты из `<head>`, а только некоторые данные. Например, разметку OpenGraph, необходимую для кнопок "Поделиться".

Подробнее об анимации используемой в примере описано [тут](http://barbajs.org/transition.html).

Собственно говоря, речь идет об этой части кода:

```
newContainer: function() {
var $newPageHead = $('<head />').html(
$.parseHTML(
newPageRawHTML.match(/<head[^>]*>([\s\S.]*)<\/head>/i)[0], document, true
)
);
},

done: function() {
var headTags = [
"meta[name='keywords']",
"meta[name='description']",
"meta[property^='og']",
"meta[name^='twitter']",
"meta[itemprop]",
"link[itemprop]",
"link[rel='prev']",
"link[rel='next']",
"link[rel='canonical']"
].join(',');
$('head').find(headTags).remove();
$newPageHead.find(headTags).appendTo('head');
}
```

Этой частью кода я хочу извлечь определенные элементы из `<head>`, именно со страницы которая загружается. Затем удалить эти же элементы после окончания анимации и заменить их полученными ранее.

После окончания анимации, выбранные элементы исчезают, но, новые не добавляются. Что еще изменить уже и не знаю. Потыкать код можно [тут](https://plnkr.co/edit/MRgZ6oE5s17QugpST5so?p=preview).

---

Итак. **Немного дополним вопрос!**
Удалось разобраться с перезагрузкой мета-тегов. С этим проблем нет и постинг работает корректно. Так же, удалось разобраться с анимацией. Фактически, без труда все это связывается с animate.css и можно лепить разную анимацию для разных кнопок. Посмотреть можно [тут](https://run.plnkr.co/plunks/McOROzi0kOqIhLeVQkFT/).

Нерешенным сейчас остается только вопрос с перезагрузкой скриптов. Например, в том же примере, на странице контактов встроена карта. Попытки запустить initmap.js через скрипт barba.js не увенчались успехом. Если кто допилит этот момент - будет просто прекрасно!

Вот он [код на Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/McOROzi0kOqIhLeVQkFT?p=preview).

Comment: А цель какая? При подобных подходах содержимое `<head>` остается и, по-хорошему, должно оставаться неизменным, будучи загруженным в первый раз.

Comment: Система генерирует скрипт в верхней части для разных страниц. Соответсвенно без подгрузки этого скрипта, при переходе на страницу с формой обратной связи происходит ошибка во время отправки. Например, на 1-й странице будет `<script type="text/javascript" src="/cgi/uutils.fcg?a=uSD&amp;ca=2&amp;r=0.642405327684976"></script>`, а на второй - `<script type="text/javascript" src="/cgi/uutils.fcg?a=uSD&amp;ca=2&amp;r=0.534562346546546"></script>`. Остальные данные в `<head>` остаются без изменений.

Comment: Скрипт можно разместить в `<body>`, тогда при переходах между страницами у вас он точно будет меняться в верстке. Но будет ли исполняться - вопрос. Можно проверить.

Comment: То, что скрипты можно размещать в перезагружаемом блоке я знаю. Для меня этот вариант не подходит. Впрочем, я немного изменю задачу и сейчас дополню описание с примером на Plunker.

Answer (score 1):

Был получен ответ от автора в английской версии SO. Для решения этой задачи лучше использовать [Events](http://barbajs.org/events.html) после анимации:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {

            Barba.Pjax.init();
            Barba.Prefetch.init();

            var FadeTransition = Barba.BaseTransition.extend({
                    start: function() {
                        Promise
                            .all([this.newContainerLoading, this.fadeOut()])
                            .then(this.fadeIn.bind(this));
                    },

                    fadeOut: function() {
                        return $(this.oldContainer).animate({
                             opacity: 0
                        }).promise();
                    },

                    fadeIn: function() {
                        var _this = this;
                        var $el = $(this.newContainer);

                        $(this.oldContainer).hide();

                        $el.css({
                            visibility: 'visible',
                            opacity: 0
                        });

                        $el.animate({
                            opacity: 1
                        }, 400, function() {
                            _this.done();
                        });
                    }
            });

            Barba.Pjax.getTransition = function() {
                return FadeTransition;
            };

            Barba.Dispatcher.on('newPageReady', function(currentStatus, oldStatus, container, newPageRawHTML) {
          // html head parser borrowed from jquery pjax
          var $newPageHead = $( '<head />' ).html(
              $.parseHTML(
                  newPageRawHTML.match(/<head[^>]*>([\s\S.]*)<\/head>/i)[0]
                , document
                , true
              )
          );
          var headTags = [
              "meta[name='keywords']"
            , "meta[name='description']"
            , "meta[property^='og']"
            , "meta[name^='twitter']"
            , "meta[itemprop]"
            , "link[itemprop]"
            , "link[rel='prev']"
            , "link[rel='next']"
            , "link[rel='canonical']"
          ].join(',');
          $( 'head' ).find( headTags ).remove(); // Remove current head tags
          $newPageHead.find( headTags ).appendTo( 'head' ); // Append new tags to the head
      });

        });
    </script>
```

Результат смотрим [тут](https://plnkr.co/edit/wfgMT7kbvX3mhoGDggli?p=preview).